# Авторизация на форумах через Python

Tags: python, авторизация, форум, ipb

Задача такая . Есть 100 форумов , и все они на одном движке. Как осуществить авторизацию в форумах циклично. То есть , вводиться форум, на него передается логин и пароль и идет авторизация. Что бы не парсингом каждого форума , а как бы шаблонно.Может есть какой нибудь API этого движка, что бы с помощю одной функции войти на разные форумы.

Comment: Смотрите какой запрос посылается браузером на сайт форума при авторизации и повторите его в скрипте

Comment: Он будет одинаковый у всех форумах этого движка ?

Comment: Думаю да, стоит проверить на некоторой выборке из сайтов эту идею

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: К сожалению , но запрос у всех форумов разный.

Comment: Все форумы используют IPB движок . Есть ли у API этого движка некая функция авторизации ? 
Или может попробовать парсить каждый сайт ?

Comment: Похоже что есть, но гугл выдал что-то невнятное. Попробуйте распарсить, как вариант скиньте ссылку на один из тех форумов -- попробую зарегаться и залогиниться, если что в ответ выложу код

Comment: Да , я API тоже не смог найти. 
Вот http://www.maultalk.com один из форумов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример авторизации на сайте.

Регистрировался на временную почту, так что она вполне может скоро превратиться для того сайта "в тыкву".

Когда в `requests.post` заполняется параметр `data`, это указывает ему заполнять запрос как будто он был отправлен из формы на сайте. Так что на том сайте в форме для логина есть два поля `UserName` и `PassWord`, чьи значения при логине подставляются и отправляются.

`requests` очень умный, т.к. после post-запроса следует редирект на главную страницу с включением в тот запрос редиректа куков, полученных из post-запроса:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    'UserName': 'sidubi',
    'PassWord': 'sidubi@p33.org',
}

rs = requests.post('http://www.maultalk.com/ipb.html?act=Login&CODE=01', data=data)
print(rs)  # <Response [200]>
print(rs.url)  # http://www.maultalk.com/ipb.html

# Проверка удачной авторизации
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')
print(root.select_one('#userlinks > p.home > b').text)  # Вошли как:  sidubi
```

Comment: Да все верно , но ведь название полей входа у разных сайтов по разному. Что с этим делать ?

Comment: Да и проверку ведь можно сделать по респонсу , так ведь ?

Comment: @YourCircle, вряд ли разные, но тут проверять нужно, ну если разные, то для каждого сайта свои поля: username, login, и т.п. А по респонсу вы вряд ли проверите -- попробуйте ввести другой пароль, уверен будет также 200, но в самой странице будет текст про неправильный логин/пароль

Comment: Да по респонсу проверил , не работает , все так же 200. А вот на счет полей , я так подумал, по идее на странице авторизации чаще всего присутствуют всего 2 поля . По их именам можно не заморачиваться , а просто Grabом отловить и все. Что по этому поводу думаете ?

Comment: @YourCircle, угу, поля авторизации можно вытащить (grab, lxml, beatifulsoup, и т.п.) и с ними сделать post-запрос для авторизации